# Как защитить домашнюю Wi-Fi сеть от взлома?

Tags: wifi, роутер, безопасность

Здравствуйте! У меня стоит роутер `TP-Link TD-W8101G`. Защита `WPA-2 PSK`. Шифрование `AES`. Пароль из 16 символов в котором присутствуют и цифры и буквы. Логин и пароль для доступа настройкам роутера поставтил свои (~10 символов). Но мой роутер постоянно кто-то взламывает.(уже 5 раз). Каждый раз взомщик меняет имя сети и пароль к ней. Все подключенные устройства проверил на вирусы(Ничего не обнаружил). Фильтр по MAC-адрессам включать не хочу, потому что у смартфона, как я заметил, меняется MAC-адресс после каждой перезагрузки. После каждого взлома сбрасываю настройки роутера к заводским и заново настраиваю. Можно ли как-нибудь защитить роутер от этих взломов? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Может его по ethernet ломают? У смартфона мак при перезагрузке меняться не должен

Comment: Может Вас из интернет через порт wan ломают? WiFi защищен у Вас хорошо а доступ к настройкам роутера ? [ЗАЩИТА МАРШРУТИЗАТОРА ИЛИ КАК ЗАЙТИ В ГОСТИ ЧЕРЕЗ ЧЕРНЫЙ ХОД](http://helpsetup.ru/internet/login_parol_marshrutizator.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. WPA2-PSK не так просто взломать, если почти невозможно. Ты можешь попрбовать посавить пароль еще подлиннее. 64-знака. Посмотри на реакцию злодея. Если опять влзомает, то значит дело не в пароле, а в каком-то из следующих пунктов.
2. Не забывай запаролить админку как следует, а лучше еще и пользователя с хитрым именем поставить.
3. Не исключенно, что кто-то из знакомых тебе поставил key-logger и тупо знает все твои пароли и прикалывается над тобой.
4. Не исключенно, что есть дырки в прошивке твоего роутера. Обнови firmware. *Я не гуглил конкретно по твоему роутеру, но это возможно*.
5. Не исключено, что в роутере есть общеизвестные бэкдоры (backdoor). В этом случае могу посоветовать поставить открытую прошивку DD-WRT.
6. Если у роутера есть WPS, то знай, что эта функция имеет дыру (по крайней мере раньше была).
7. Ну и смотри другой ответ. Может его и вправду через локалку ломают?! На вирусы проверься. [Вот пример такого вируса.](http://www.antiviruses.ru/rssnews/2293/)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую усложнить пороль.

Comment: Ну что? Помогло?

Comment: Да,  помогло. Прошло время и не взломали. Спасибо, ваши советы мне помогли.

Comment: Взлом вай-фая не так сложен на самом деле - если рядом есть практикующий ново-хакер с прямыми руками, то он/она сможет взломать пароль сложностью до 16 символов в течении суток, а с помощью интернет-ресурсов и того быстрее. Главное это вытащить момент handshaking'а и использовать его для расшифровки - в Интернете полно примеров как это сделать с помощью хакерских дистрибутивов. Трудно поверить что у вашего телефона меняется MAC, т.к поставив фильтрацию только на адреса доверенных устройств вы сможете полностью предотвратить эти взломы.

Answer (score 3):

2 этапа атаки:
1. Подключиться - по WiFi (подбор ключа сети или перехват) или Ethernet (локальный нехороший) или с сети провайдера - Wan доступ к админке открыт?
Отрубить WPS, через него процесс перебора пароля сводится к подбору 2 паролей по 4 символа.

2. Подобрать пароль администратора
   на полноценном сервере предложил бы поставить Fail2Ban и забыть о проблеме. 
   Но здесь можно только усложнить, как уже посоветовали - пароль, а можно еще и добавить нового пользователя со случайным именем, дать ему все права администратора, а старого пользователя удалить. Теперь злому человеку придётся подбирать и логин и пароль

Если атака идёт со стороны провайдера, написать заявление о взломе, зачем-то ведь есть у нас отдел К.

Если атака идёт с улицы/соседей по WiFi, передвинуть роутер, чтобы не светил на всю улицу, убавить мощность сигнала в настройках, переобозвать точку доступа и сделать SSID скрытым, это чуть усложнит задачу в сумме.

Но если есть уязвимости в прошивке, то перебор и не нужен, тут уже затыкать дыры (и не факт, что есть новая прошивка). Искать в настройках всё, связанное с безопасностью, запретить UPnP. Если есть авторизация 802.1X, то включить еще и её.

Как вариант, сменить роутер на микротик. Если мозгов хватит настроить, гибкости хватит запретить что угодно.

Comment: С роскомнадзором за интернетом скоро отдел К станет не нужным.